# What is this new insane trend to remove the "order by" feature from websites?

Tags: usability, website-design, user-behavior, navigation, user-expectation

In the last couple of months, two major websites I use have **removed** the entire basic feature to order the list of items in any way other than by "relevance", if it even mentions what it orders by at all.

One of them is a very major online grocery store, so there is no longer any way to sort by the price, for example.

The other is actually (no, I'm not making this up) a **price comparison** website, where the whole point is that you search for products to see who sells them at the lowest price. Except that now it's impossible to sort by price; instead it's all "by relevance".

"Relevance" of course being undefined and fuzzy.

In both cases, I contacted them and asked about it, and got very generic responses of the typical kind when companies have a policy to answer e-mails but not actually answer any question.

Is this some disturbing new "trend" of completely crippling the users?

Comment: By relevance from my observation is either featured "sponsored" products and or algorithm-generated recommendations made from past purchases, searches, and who knows what else. Probably methods to combat inflation.

Comment: never saw this, at least not in any major brand, do you have any examples?

Comment: Unfortunately, without talking to the product owners, strategists and designers directly, we are unlikely to ever know the 'correct' answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've correctly pointed out that 'relevance' is relative term. However, this basically unpacks to 'what converts best'. Whether the websites you refer to cater to businesses or consumers, they're going to present their offering in a way that most benefits their users. In other words, what is most 'relevant' to them.

Here are some possible reasons for the design updates you observed:

- They're A/B testing, to compare how two or more experiences impact conversion rates.
- They've found that how they're presenting their offering converts best (now or in the future). Remember that some business models will favor maximizing margin over quantity sold. Presenting low margin items goes against a brand identity in some cases, which will be reflected in the interface and overall experience.
- They've made a mistake, or they haven't given it enough thought. The size of a business often does not scale proportionally to the delightfulness of a user experience.

Remember that 'you are not (always) the user'. In other words, what works for you may not necessarily align with these websites' business goals.

Comment: "they're going to present their offering in a way that most benefits their users" if you want to believe that? correct is: they're going to present their offering in a way that most benefits their business.

Comment: @Mischa, why so cynical? A business has no business if they have no value to their users, and their benefit always comes first.

Comment: This is not cynical, just another perspective. The objective of every company is to make profit (except for NGOs). Then they will think: how can we sell best our product? Another question is also: what is the product, who is customer? If you, as the user, doesn't pay for the service, you might be the product (and other companies the actual customer). So now the company (for example the price comparison website) might think: if we present the products of our customers to the consumers (the users) in a 'most relevant' order, we can sell the products of our real customers better to the consumers.

Comment: Also there was never a company sacrificing UX for profit. (not cynicism but sarcasm ;)

Comment: I was talking basic business philosophy, where a proposition has to align with a user's benefit for anything to be profitable. I don't see how there's any other perspective on that.

Comment: Yes, me too. What if we say "they're going to present their offering in a way that most benefits their customers" - because user = customer = consumer is not true. If a business changes their product to present only the "most relevant" products, that will of course benefit their customers, but not their users (consumers). Could we agree on that?

Comment: @Mischa, I don't think what I wrote needs any polishing. When I talk about users in a commercial context, it's pretty obvious these are 'customers'. To nitpick about it is futile and I don't really want to engage you in any further discussion about it.